# "Mary is at home." / "Mary is in the room."

Tags: prepositions

We use preposition "at" with home:

> Mary is **at** home.

and we use preposition "in" with room / kitchen ...:

> Mary is **in** the room.

Is there any rules or Is it common to use it like that?

I couldn't find rule mach with above use in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place):

> **We use *at*:**
>
> - to refer to a position or location which we see as a point
> - to talk about locations at companies, workplaces when we see them as a place of activity
> - to refer to activities which involve a group of people:
> - with school/college/university
> - to refer to an address
> - to talk about public places where we get treatments, such as a hairdresser’s or doctor’s surgery
> - to refer to most shops

Comment: The rules are descriptions of common use.

Comment: Thank you @TRomano, I like your comment, I'll use it as a quote.

Comment: Generally it depends on whether you are referring to a location or to existence within some enclosed area. "*At* the store" (location), "*in* the store" (within an enclosed area) etc.